# Gloves weight for muay thai/boxing training

Tags: rules, equipment, boxing

I am starting to train for muay thai / boxing, and

I would like to know if there is any weight restriction for gloves.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a shopping question, of a type that Stack Exchange does not cover.

Comment: The answer to this question makes it clear that the closing reason is not justified. And question was never about shopping gloves.

Comment: The fact that someone can give an answer is irrelevant to whether the question is of a certain category, be it on-topic or off-topic. The question here requests specific personal advice that will almost certainly never help anybody except the original asker, and that advice is on the particular items the asker should obtain. **It is therefore a shopping question, is off-topic, and should be closed.** Editing to make it a general question about the factors that go into making the decision, so that many users can apply the information in answers, is what could happen to keep it on-topic and open

Comment: @Multitut I edited your question to make it more general to make it on-topic for the site, if you disagree with edit please roll back edit.

Comment: @Nij Sir, I tried to make it general but there is not much to it, maybe OP sees this and changes something.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to approach this question:

1. What the rules permit for your weight class
2. What your training instructor recommend

The World Muay Thai Council's [rules](http://www.wmcmuaythai.org/about-muaythai/muaythai-rules/3-gloves) state in section 3.3:

> *3.3*. The glove sizes for competitions are as follows:
>
> - The boxers between the Mini Flyweight division and the Featherweight division must use the gloves of six (6) ounces (132
>     grams).
> - The boxers between the Super Featherweight division and the Welterweight division must use the gloves of eight (8) ounces (227
>     grams).
> - The boxers between the Super Welterweight division and over must use the gloves of ten (10) ounces (284 grams).

The [USMTA](http://www.usmta.com/usmta-rules-regs.htm) also uses rules listed above, with this addendum for section 3.2:

> Gloves at 12 oz, 14oz, 16oz, 18oz can be used for higher weights.
>
> The weight of the leather shall not be more than half of the total
>   glove weight, including the internal cushioning, which should always
>   be in good condition. The laces are to be tied at the back of the
>   wrist band. Gloves with Velcro fastening may also be used.

So it seems that you'd need gloves of at least 10 oz. for competition - perhaps larger ones if required for your weight class.

However, you should consult with your trainer/instructor to determine what type of gloves you should use for training. Perhaps he/she might want you to use heavier gloves to work on endurance, or gloves with more padding for protection.

Comment: Sir I edited the question and if there is anything that you need to change please look into it.